# Can I convert .apk files to html5?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

Can I convert .apk files to html5?

I need to modify an existing app, but don't know how to handle .apk.. if there is any tool that can covert it into html5 tht would save me.

Let me know..

Thanks.

Comment: is it a hybrid app or native?

Answer (score 2):

An `apk` file is just a `jar` file for Android. You can unpack it using `unzip`, `jar`, etc., which will extract any HTML files within (if any).

If the app you're trying to work with isn't actually an HTML5 app, then there probably won't be any HTML files for you to play with. There is no automatic way to convert a native app to HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, [some tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2251719) can help you to decompile apk to java, but not HTML5

Answer (score 0):

.apk files cannot be converted to .html files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it Straight away.. First you should get the Source Code of an APK then you should check whether the www or assets folder contains HTML Codes. If the App is created through PhoneGap you can do that.. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your apk file.
Then go to that folder and click on the assets folder in which you will find your **www** folder.

So in your **www** folder you will find your html, js, css files.

But the main thing is that

> your project must be the phonegap project or hybrid project.

Answer (score -1):

i tried using "apk editor.apk" and i also opened the assets folder and i saw a bunch of xml , html and some other files, then you can see some html5 files. here is the link to download apk editor 
https://apkpure.com/apk-editor-pro/com.heagoo.apkeditor

Comment: This does not answer the question